# How to add dynamic forms on rails and save results to mongodb(mongoid)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am new to ruby on rails 5, I'm attempting to make a "survey app" that enables a user to dynamically add questions as dynamic forms to the survey. I managed to get it running but the add question button does not add a question form, the delete button does not delete the question form.

Once I fill in the fields and click on the submit button, it only saves the user `group` attribute, which I have specified in survey model.

Can anyone please assist in making the form add more questions and be able to delete it by user?

[image: snapshot of survey form]

*models/survey.rb*

```
class Survey
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true

  field :group_id, type: String
end
```

*models/question.rb*

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :qtype, type: String
  field :tittle, type: String
  field :qline, type: String

  belongs_to :survey, optional: true
end
```

*controllers/survey_controller.rb*

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  @survey.questions.build
end

def create
  @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @survey.save
      format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

*surveys/form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <div class="field-input">
    <%= f.label :group_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :group_id %>
  </div>

  <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>question type</th>
        <th>tittle</th>
        <th>write question</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='fields'>
      <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'question', f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <%= link_to_add_row('Add Question', f, :questions, class: 'btn btn-
     primary') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*_question.html.erb*

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy, as: :hidden %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', class: 'remove_record' %>
  </td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :qtype, label: true %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :tittle, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :qline, label: false, as: :string %></td>
</tr>
```

_application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_row(name, f, association, **args)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|     
      render(association.to_s.singularize, f: builder) 
    end
    link_to(name, 'new', class: "add_fields " + args[:class], data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

*script*

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('form').on('click', '.remove_record', function(event) {
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1');
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    return event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    var regexp, time;
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $('.fields').append($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
    return event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you follow the orthodox approach (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#usage) instead of writing your own helper method `link_to_add_row` and JavaScript to make them work?

Comment: Thank you @JagdeepSingh , the github link helped alot.